# Collision in console based game not working

Tags: python, console, collision

I have two methods inside of my board class to check for collision. One for other player objects and one for the borders of the map. The one for the map is working fine but collision for the players is off.
Here are the methods:

```
def check_mob(self, player, enemy):
    dx = player.x - enemy.x
    dy = player.y - enemy.y
    distance = math.sqrt(dx ** 2 + dy ** 2)
    if distance <= 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def check_brd(self, board, player, enemy, direction):
    '''Deals with collision '''
    brd_x = len(self.board)
    brd_y = len(self.board[0])
    if direction == 'down':
        if player.x + 1 == brd_x or self.check_mob(player, enemy):
            return False
        else:
            return True
    elif direction == 'up':
        if player.x - 1 == brd_x - brd_x -1 or self.check_mob(player, enemy):
            return False
        else:
            return True
    elif direction == 'left':
        if player.y - 1 == brd_y - brd_y - 1 or self.check_mob(player, enemy):
            return False
        else:
            return True
    elif direction == 'right':
        if player.y + 1 == brd_y or self.check_mob(player, enemy):
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

The player or enemy will walk up to the other and get stuck. I need them to be able to walk away from each other when this happens.
The entire, now working, code is [here.](http://pastebin.com/aGf7QTvb)

Comment: Show us what you do with the players after a collision was detected.

Comment: As in when the function is called? I don't think I'm doing anything once collision is detected.

Comment: You must be doing something, otherwise the players would be walking trough each other or through walls.

Comment: Yes we need more details to help here. What do you mean by get stuck? If you think you are telling them to move apart then we need to see the code that does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check_mob is testing for collision at the current position, not the position where the player is trying to go...
Also simplify

```
player.x - 1 == brd_x - brd_x -1
```

to

```
player.x == 0
```

Comment: Also it is would be clearer to separate things: check_brd only does the edges, check_mob only does the enemy, then call both of them rather than calling check_mob from inside check_brd

Comment: I just can't seem to wrap my head around this. I know what needs to happen but I don't know how to put it into code.

Comment: First trim out the enemy logic from check_brd. Second add direction as argument to check_mob so you can check the position the player is aiming for, instead of the position where he currently is. Third call both functions and move only if both return True.

Comment: Oh my lord. Thank you so much. I've got it working now. I was nearly ready to give up for the night. Also, I'll post the new, updated, code in the pastebin link so that anyone that wants to can check it out.